# HTML Layout for Website Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: html, css, alignment, mediawiki

I am using MediaWiki to make a wiki for an online game. However, I cannot seem to fix this simple bug. See the screen shot. Please disregard the media wiki code, like the '''. They mean the bold tag. Everything seemed to be going fine with this code, but I think the problem has something to do with the align=. Thank you in advanced.

```
<table border="1" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 25%;" align="left">
<tr>
<td height="30px" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background-color: #639CFB;">Wiki Links</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height: 190px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #C5D8FF;"><div id="zonecontent" style="margin: 5px;">
<ul>
<li>[http://link.com/to/contact/page Website Support]</li>
</ul>
</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 25%;" align="left">
<tr>
<td height="30px" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background-color: #639CFB;">Zone iPhone Support</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height: 190px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #C5D8FF;"><div id="zonecontent" style="margin: 5px;">All content goes here.</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 25%;" align="left">
<tr>
<td height="30px" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background-color: #639CFB;">Zone iPhone Staff Information</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height: 190px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #C5D8FF;"><div id="zonecontent" style="margin: 5px;">All content goes here.</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 25%;">
<tr>
<td height="30px" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background-color: #639CFB;">Zone iPhone Shops</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height: 190px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #C5D8FF;"><div id="zonecontent" style="margin: 5px;">All content goes here.</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 25%;" align="left">
<tr>
<td height="30px" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background-color: #639CFB;">Zone iPhone Staff Events</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height: 190px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #C5D8FF;"><div id="zonecontent" style="margin: 5px;">All content goes here.</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 25%;" align="left">
<tr>
<td height="30px" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background-color: #639CFB;">Zone iPhone Games</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height: 190px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #C5D8FF;"><div id="zonecontent" style="margin: 5px;">All content goes here.</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 25%;" align="left">
<tr>
<td height="30px" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background-color: #639CFB;">NPC Information</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height: 190px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #C5D8FF;"><div id="zonecontent" style="margin: 5px;">All content goes here.</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 25%;" align="left">
<tr>
<td height="30px" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background-color: #639CFB;">External Links</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height: 190px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #C5D8FF;"><div id="zonecontent" style="margin: 5px;">All content goes here.</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 50%;">
<tr>
<td height="30px" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background-color: #639CFB;">About Zone iPhone</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height: 190px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #C5D8FF;"><div id="zonecontent" style="margin: 5px;">'''Zone iPhone''' is an iOS server made to bring the GraalOnline Server Zone to life on mobile devices. It has vast battlegrounds and fighting with guns. Players can spar each other, help each other on missions, or visit other planets so they can win it. Players can also participate in many events and mini-games, including a similar game to Bomberman.<br /><br />'''Genre:''' Massively Multiplayer Online Role Playing Game<br />'''Date of Release:''' December 17, 2012<br />'''Owner:''' Eurocenter Games<br />'''Manager:''' Matt</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The Screenshot:

[image: The Screenshot]

Comment: Could you simplify your code to remove code that is not directly relevant to the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `<table>` for layout. Your data being displayed is not tabular data, therefore do not use `<table>`.

Use a block element, like `<div>` and set them to float or flow in the logical page order. Not only will it solve the problem you're having, but your markup will be considerably cleaner and web spiders will make better sense of it.

Of course, if you're using MediaWiki why aren't you using MediaWiki syntax for HTML generation?

Comment: I am not entirely knowledgeable with MediaWiki syntax because this is my first wiki site. Thanks for the tip though. I thought making a table would be easier.

Comment: Edit: Thanks, I have transitioned to <div>. I thought about using div before, but thought tables were easier. So far, I've matched the design from the table script into div. It is much easier!